# Approximation method for combinations

Tags: combinatorics, approximation, combinations

I have the expression:

$$\frac{{D+\frac{k}{\theta}}\choose D-z}{{1+m}\choose{D-z}}$$

In the above expression, $m$, $k$, $\theta$, and $D$ are constants.

What is the approximation of the above expression?

Regards

Comment: Expand into factorials, and use Stirling's approximation for large factorials. Without more detailed information on your constants, it is hard to say more.

Comment: @vonbrand if the combination is xC2 (i.e., `x` choose 2), could you say more?